# Change Xamarin Forms default colour (grey) to black?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

By default, it seems that the background is white and the labels are grey. This looks bad. I would change the labels' colour to complete black.

But I do not want to set the TextColor individually. There must be a way to change the default label color at once. I looked into the shared module, but I cannot find anything. The sytles.xml in the Android project does not have the grey colour. Where can I find it?

Comment: there are two want to set this one is create style and set it and another way create label render and set textcolor property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this many ways but simplest way is using custom control

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
  public MyLabel ()
  {
    BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
  }
}
```

You can use using this :

```
<MyLabel Text="This is testing" />
```

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction/

**OR**

Set style in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Gray" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Actually, before posting this question, I did add the same Style to not Application but to Grid (in which labels are) or ContentPage's Resources. But that crashed the app. Why didn't it work?

Comment: Ah. I had added <Style> right under <ContentPage.Resources>. I added <ResourceDictionary>, and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change TextColor of all label then you can do it from implicit style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

And add this to resource dictionary of App.xaml